# android webview camera not released when app in background

Tags: java, android, webview, camera

I use android webview to load a web ar site.
It will open camera success.
But when I go to android home, the android privacy indicator still is green, it means background app still use camera.
How do I release the camera usage when webview app enter background?

Below is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 101);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        settings.setUserAgentString(WebSettings.getDefaultUserAgent(this) + " ViverseApp/1.0 HTCVRSDET");
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        settings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);


        settings.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);

        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                return false;
            }

        });
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){

            @Override
            public void onPermissionRequest(PermissionRequest request) {
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        request.grant(request.getResources());
                    }
                });

            }
        });
        CookieManager m = CookieManager.getInstance();
        m.setAcceptCookie(true);
        
        webView.loadUrl("https://hiukim.github.io/mind-ar-js-doc/face-tracking-samples/minimal.html");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(webView != null) {
            webView.pauseTimers();
            webView.onPause();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(webView != null) {
            webView.resumeTimers();
            webView.onResume();
        }
    }
}
```

Updated:

We can try this url in chrome/edge/firefox:
https://hiukim.github.io/mind-ar-js-doc/face-tracking-samples/minimal.html

In chrome/edge, camera will be release  when back to home. But in firefox, it also has the problem.

Comment: There isn't any piece of code where you create/init/start the Camera....so how can we help you? As you start it, you need to clear/free it. If it is opened in Javascript from your Webview, you need to intercept "page leave" event and destroy it from javascript. If it is intercepted by Java, you need to do it by detecting VebView change page.

Comment: I just test with web ar page, camera is controlled by web page.